# How to unbind nginx (or any process) from a port?

Tags: linux

Is there a way to unbind a port without killing the process bounded to it?

I thought I told `nginx` to not bind to port 80 by changing all conf files to 8800. But `apache` says it can't start because port 80 is bound. `netstat` confirms this.

Is there a way to force `nginx` to unbind from port 80 without killing the `nginx` process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no generic way.  You have to modify the daemon's configuration file and force it to reload configuration (or restart it).

Comment: So maybe this is too complicated of a question, but how is the port mapping operationally stored? as in: is the port mapping simply some data structure in RAM under kernel access only? otherwise I would assume that there is some theoretical way for root user to force changes.

Comment: Excellent question, but not one I can answer with confidence, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what distro you have but in a Fedora/RH-based system:

According to `/etc/init.d/nginx` the `service nginx reload` sends a `HUP` signal which is a graceful restart (i.e., will not terminate current sessions but will wait for them to clear).

Equivalent: `kill -HUP <nginx pid>`

For explanation of the signals that `nginx` accepts, check [this document](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxCommandLine#Stopping_or_Restarting_Nginx) out.

Comment: I actually wanted to if there was a general way to unbind ports irrelevant of what the process was. I would have rather eliminated the specifics and kept it general, but oh well. Do you know if I should ask the general question as another question, or revert this question?

Comment: The last line in your question led me to believe that you were targeting `nginx` specifically. My apologies. Please modify the question to better reflect what you meant to ask. I strongly suspect that there is no way to generally unbind a process from a port without killing the process but I'd be interested to discover otherwise :-).